# CSS Div Layout stretch to fit width and height

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to make a phpBB theme, but am having trouble setting up the DIV's the way I envisioned the page to be.

This is what I am looking to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhQpm.jpg (image to help with understanding)

This is what I had so far.

index.html

```
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='header'>
    </div>

    <div id='sidemenu'>
    </div>

    <div id='content'>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

css.css

```
 *{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px
    }

 #header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#6FF;
    }

 #sidemenu {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#6F6;
    }
```

The problem with this is that the sidemenu DIV overflows to the bottom of the page and creates a scrollbar.

I have tried looking for a solution, and only managed to get the overflow to go away by using `bottom:0px;` inside the sidemenu css

But this pushes the header to the right, and sidemenu to the top left corner like this..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpV24.jpg

I am stuck here, css gives me a huge headache ahaha. Can anyone please help me with a solution?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `height:calc(100% - 50px);   top:50px;` for your sidemenu. Run the snippet bellow.

```css
 *{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px
    }

 #header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#6FF;
    }
html,body,#container{height:100%;}

 #sidemenu {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
   top:50px;
    background-color:#6F6;
    }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='header'>
    </div>

    <div id='sidemenu'>
    </div>

    <div id='content'>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That is beautiful, thank you! Didn't know you can do that in css. I hope it's cross browser friendly.